# The Right Way To Minimize Memory Usage With Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have two scenarios in Netty where I am trying to minimize memory copies and optimize memory usage:

(1) Reading a very large frame (20 Megabites).

(2) Reading lots of very little frames (20 megabites at 50 bites per frame) to rebuild into one message at a higher level in the pipeline.

For the first scenario, as I get a length at the beginning of the frame, I extended FrameDecoder. Unfortunately as I don't see how to return the length to Netty (I only indicate whether the frame is complete or not), I believe Netty is going through multiple fill buffer, copy and realloc cycles thus using for more memory than is required. Is there something I am missing here? Or should I be avoiding the FrameDecoder entirely if I expect this scenario?

In the second scenario, I am currently creating a linked list of all the little frames which I wrap using ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer (which I can then wrap in a ChannelBufferInputStream), but I am again using far more memory than I expected to use (perhaps because the allocated ChannelBuffers have spare space?). Is this the right way to use Netty ChannelBuffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it appeared the best way to handle my FrameDecoder issue was to write my own on top of the SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler. As soon as I determined the length from the header, I created the ChannelBuffer with size exactly matching the length. This (along with other changes) significantly improved the memory performance of my application.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a specialized version of frame decoder called, LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder. Its handy, when you have a header with message length. It can even extract the message length from header by giving an offset.
2. Actually, ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer does not creates copies of received data, it creates a composite buffer from given buffers, so your received frame data will not be copied. If you are holding the composite buffers/ your custom wrapper in the code and forgot to nullify, memory leaks can happen.

These are practices I follow,

- Allocate direct buffers for long lived objects, slice it on use.
- when I want to join/encode multiple buffers into one big buffer. I Use ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer
- If I have a buffer and want to do something with it/portion of it, I make a slice of it by calling slice or slice(0,..) on channel buffer instance
- If I have a channel buffer and know the position of data which is small, I always use getXXX methods
- If I have a channel buffer, which is used in many places for make something out of it, always make it modifiable, slice it on use.

Note: channelbuffer.slice does not make a copy of the data, it creates a channel buffer with new reader & write index.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but you are pretty much indicating what I am already doing. The LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder, as it extends Frame Decoder, inherits its issues (you can't avoid the fill buffer/realloc and copy cycles). I know that wrappedBuffer does not create copies but I am still using much more memory than expected (heap increased 3-4 times the message size).

Comment: @Gareth Without seeing the code, its hard to tell any thing.I just checked the FrameDecoder and and found out that, It is using DynamicChannel buffer witch starts from 256 bytes, so I am not sure how its going to grow when you receive 20MBs, I think, its better to write your own version of FrameDecoder with a fixed buffer.